# Find Max number from unique values in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, max, distinct

Hi I'm trying to get a unique list of ID values based on the latest (max) version number

My table looks like:

```
id  Version    Cost      Name     Status
---|-----|------------|--------|---------
35 | 1.0 | 200000     | john   | Open
36 | 1.0 | 400000     | juliet | Open
35 | 2.0 | 350000     | borat  | Closed
36 | 1.5 | 30000      | john   | Waiting Update
```

I want it to be able to return

```
id  Version    Cost      Name     Status
---|-----|------------|--------|---------
35 | 2.0 | 350000     | borat  | Closed
36 | 1.5 | 30000      | john   | Waiting Update
```

I've tried using this but can't get it to work and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

```
select FB.* from CSLL.Feedback FB

inner join (
    select ID
    ,max(Version)
    ,Status as MaxID
    from CSLL.Feedback
    group by ID
) groupedID

ON FB.ID = groupedID.ID
AND FB.Version = groupedID.MaxID
and FB.Status = groupedID.Status
```

Which was based on a response to another question found here

[LINKY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Can anyone help at all?

Many thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: Solved it with this in case anyone is interested:

  "  select ID, max(Version), Status from CSLL.Feedback

    Group By ID, Status "

If there is a better way of doing it please say

Comment: Yes. The version you had before was better, but this bit was (obviously?) wrong: "AND FB.Version = groupedID.MaxID"... and so (potentially) was this bit " ,max(Version),Status as MaxID". Look again at the examples provided.

Comment: @Strawberry It all seems fine there other then my bad name calling (have renamed MaxID to MaxVersion). After removing the parts referencing the status column it works fine. Any thoughts to getting this included as well? Many Thanks,

Comment: @Strawberry - Spoke to soon. It is now returning everything

`select FB.* from CSLL.Feedback FB

inner join (
 select ID
 ,max(Version) as MaxVersion
 from CSLL.Feedback
 group by ID
) groupedID

ON FB.ID = groupedID.ID
AND FB.Version = groupedID.MaxVersion`

Comment: Looks good to me. Perhaps your error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select fb1.* from Feedback fb1 
LEFT JOIN Feedback fb2 on fb2.id=fb1.id and fb2.version>fb1.version
where fb2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to work - Comes back with 'incorrect syntax near feedback'

Comment: I have edited my answer.I forgot to write from in query.